# the form of classes in $K(X)$ [Atiyah]

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

Anyone can explain me why taking two bundles $E,F$ we can conclude that any element in $K(X)$ is of the form $E-F$? It is mentioned in Atiyah on the bottom of the page $43$ (I can put screen if needed).

Comment: It is in general true that if $K$ is the group formed by a semi group $A$, then elements in $K$ are given by $a-b$ for $a, b\in A$.

Comment: This is essentially how you define $K(X)$. It is known as the Grothendieck construction. Despite the serious name, it just means taking all formal differences.

Comment: Rather it is just a presentation of the data. $K(X)$ is essentially the group completion of the monoid of vector bundles over $X$ under the Whitney sum. The Grothendieck group is one way to present the data https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+completion. There are other constructions, but they are equivalent, and not really that much different.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek: Your comment is an answer; would you mind reposting it as an Answer, to remove this question from the unanswered list?